# Pass empty value to cmdlet parameter

Tags: powershell, null, parameter-passing, powershell-cmdlet

I'm writing a graphical instance of the Get-EventLog cmdlet so that I can lock down what parameters and values the user can input. In the picture below, the purple boxes (left column) will be set by me, but the tan boxes (right column) can accept user input for any value.
[image]
On the back end of this I am writing a function that will take whatever values the user inputs and calls the Get-EventLog cmdlet with those values. For instance, if the user only input a value for the newest parameter, then this would be the code it would generate:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source sourcename -Newest uservalue `
      -After $null -Before $null
```

The problem is that the cmdlet doesn't recognize `$null` as an acceptable input for the `-After` and `-Before` parameters. How do I pass an empty value to a cmdlet's parameter without throwing an error?

Comment: `-Before` and `-After` require a `DateTime` value, so you can't specify `$null`. You can, however, omit the parameter or use `[DateTime]::MinValue` or `[DateTime]::MaxValue` instead.

Comment: Yes, that would've worked for the `-After` and `-Before`, but I would've still had the problem if the user didn't input a value for `-Newest` which takes an int. Splatting seems to take care of it though. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use Splatting.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)

```
$params = @{
    LogName = 'Logname'
    Source = 'Source'
}

if ($AfterValue) {
    $params.After = $AfterValue
}

if ($BeforeValue) {
    $params.Before = $BeforeValue
}

if ($NewestValue) {
    $params.Newest = $NewestValue
}

Get-EventLog @params
```